# Kendo grid change row class not working

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid that has checkboxes for selection.
When I click a checkbox, I change the class of the row to "k-state-selected" and save the row id in

```
var checkedIds = [];
```

I then have a context menu where I can select the change I want to apply to the row.

In this case, I want to change the value Something of all rows. That works.

Then, I have this piece of code that restores the previous selected rows.

```
private setCheckRows(checkedIds) {
            $.each(checkedIds, (index, value) => {
                $("#grid  tbody").find("tr").each(
                    function () {
                        if ($(this).closest("tr").attr("Id") === value) {
                            $(this).closest("tr").addClass("k-state-selected")
                                .attr("style", "background-color: rgb(51,121,181)")
                                .find(".checkbox")
                                .attr("checked", "checked");
                        }
                    });
            });
        }
```

It works, but then again it doesn't...

If I select one checkbox, this bit of code does nothing

```
if ($(this).closest("tr").attr("Id").replace("task-row-", "") === value) {
                            $(this).closest("tr").addClass("k-state-selected")
                                .attr("style", "background-color: rgb(51,121,181)")
                                .find(".checkbox")
                                .attr("checked", "checked");

                    }
```

If I select two or more checkboxes, it works on all rows except the first.

So all rows, except the first one, are restored to being selected and with a blue background.

This is indeed a very strange behaviour.

Any ideas?
Tks in advance.

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue in [Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/)/[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it.

I changed this

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Cockpit/SetWorkflowStep",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(newTaskStatus),
                contentType: "application/json"
            }).done(() => {
                $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
                this.setCheckRows(checkedIds); 
            });
```

into this

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Cockpit/SetWorkflowStep",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(newTaskStatus),
                contentType: "application/json"
            }).done(() => {
                $("#grid").data("kendoGrid")
                          .dataSource.read()
                          .done(() => { this.setCheckRows(checkedIds); });
            });
```

Now it works fine.